# How to use openStream with viewsource mode?

Tags: java

I can open viewsource mode (Ctrl + U). I want to read text from that. I try URL.openStream() but I get SERVER null

> java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol:

How can I do it, thank you.
This is my code

```
public void viewSource(){
    try {
        URL url = new URL("view-source:https://www.google.com/");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (url.openStream());
        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            System.out.println(sc.nextLine());
        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that's throwing the exception? Can you give us an example of the URL you're trying to fetch?

Comment: Yes, i edited my post

Answer (score 1):

The primary issue here is the URL: `view-source:https://www.google.com/`

The `view-source:` bit is a web-browser-ism that isn't actually part of the URL. URL's always begin with a protocol (e.g. `https://`, `http://`, `ftp://`, `ws://`, etc) Try:

```
https://www.google.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to use openStream with view-source mode?

Everything that @Michael Powers [said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51752059/139985) is correct.  However, he has not mentioned the fundamental issue here.  That is: what you appear to be trying to do by using `view-source:` *does not make sense!!*  (At least, from the perspective of the `URL.openStream()` API.)

Why?

A `view-source:` prefix on a URL is a direction to a web browser.  What it means is something like this.

> User: "Hey Mr Browser"
>
> Browser: "What can I do for you?
>
> User: "This thing denoted by the URL after `view-source:` ..."
>
> Browser: "Yes, I am fetching it.  What now?"
>
> User: "Instead of rendering as you would normally do, just show it to me in a plain text window"
>
> Browser: "OK ... here it is."

This only makes sense as a direction to a browser, or more broadly as a direction to something that renders and displays a resource.

If we try to apply the above meaning to a URL your code, there is a conceptual problem.  The `URL.openStream` method is specified to give you a stream that consists of the raw content (as bytes!) for the HTTP response body.  There is no rendering involved.  So there is no "as you would normally do" rendering to not do.

So your code fails because the JVM cannot find a protocol handler that knows what to do with a URL with a `view-source:` protocol.

(What *could* the protocol handler do ... apart from ignoring the contextually meaningless `view-source:` direction that tells it to do something that it is already doing?)