# How to open the ViewSource of an URL directly in Java?

Tags: java, url, exception, view-source, malformedurlexception

I programmed a simple button that allows the user to open a desired website.

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL(_urlString).toURI());
```

I want another button that allows the user to open the websites sourcecode directly. I tried the following:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URL("view-source:" + _urlString).toURI());
```

But I received an "java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: view-source" exception (I suppose because it doesn't start with `http` or `https`).
Does anyone know, how to do this in Java?

Comment: If the `MalformedUrlException` contained an error message please add it as it is to your question. Have you tried using `new java.net.URI(_urlString)`? This could circumvent your problem with the malformed url.

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/51733916/407651

Comment: The exact error is "java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: view-source"

Comment: Yes, and that is the same error as in the linked question.